# Nightwatch same Test with different website in Multilingual

Tags: multilingual, nightwatch.js

I am facing a difficulty on Nightwatch :

I have several websites working on the same test script but language are different.

Therefore I create a Page for each language (UK, IT, FR ...)

the thing is I would like to call them like that :

```
"Nightwatch.js -t Test.js -e chrome -UK"
```

and in my test get the language and connect to the page correspondent

any chance someone can help me do that?

Thank you very much for any help on that issue!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create a custom command that can retrieve the command values (using native [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html) or [argv npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argv)) and format your url as desired. So your command can look like something like this:

```
"Nightwatch.js -t Test.js -e chrome --env=UK"
```

and your custom command like this:

```
//this was made purely by memory, maybe it wont work
exports.command = navigate;
var environment = require("argv").argv["env"]
function navigate() {
  var pageUrl = `https://${environment}.google.com`; //format your url as desired
  this.url(landingUrl);
  return this;
}
```

And finally in your tests you only have to call that custom command

Comment: thank you very much for your help ! I succeed in finding a solution thanks to your comment :)